# NullPointerException в PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, java

Пробую привязать OnClickListener к ImageView в классе, который наследуется от PreferenceActivity и получаю NullPointerException. Почему это происходит и как это обойти?
Класс создания окна настроек

public class CreateSettingWindow extends PreferenceActivity{

```
PreferenceScreen rootScreen;

final String TAG = "settLog";
ImageView topLine;

private void prepareScreen(){
    rootScreen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    setPreferenceScreen(rootScreen);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);

    topLine = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toplinepref);
    try{
    topLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e(TAG, "d");
        }
    });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    prepareScreen();
    setContentView(R.layout.preferencytop);
}
```

}

И вот лог:
com.example.s E/settLog﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу же в глаза бросается вызов `prepareScreen()` до `setContentView()`. Дальше не смотрел, возможно что-то ещё.